# How to design function "message was read"?

Tags: django, django-models

How to design function "message was read" ?

```
class UserProfil(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class PrivateMessage(models.Model):
    from_user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    to_user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 1):

add to PrivateMessage

`is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)`

and if the "to_user" get into the view, you can check like:

```
if user == pm.to_user and not pm.is_read:
    pm.is_read = True
    pm.save()
```